# Best practice for organizing symfony2 project services/classes

Tags: php, symfony

Some information for the beginning. I'm using 2.7.0-BETA1, but the following questions are more about Best-Practice with Symfony2.
I read the Best Practice guide from Symfony. For the basics they are good, but some things seems to be unclear to me.

We're migrating from a non-framework application to symfony2. The core part we're going to put into one bundle. (I know that there are different opinions about that.) Plugins will be under Test`\plugin\FooblaPluginBundle`

Every user can set some settings in his profile, which are saved in a table (conf) (Fields: id, category, key, value, accountid)
I just began to write a service. (Just began, because I got unsure about the right way)

```
<?php
namespace Test\CoreBundle\core;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Configuration {

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function loadAll($accountid = '1') {
         $conf = $this->em->getRepository('TestCoreBundle:Conf')->findAllByAccount('1');
         dump($conf);
    }
}
```

In the end the Controller would to something like

```
$conf = $this->get('test.conf');
$conf->setCategory('foobla');
$conf->get('keyname');
```

Just to complete the code: (services.yml)

```
services:
test.conf:
    class: Test\CoreBundle\core\Configuration
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager  ]
```

Is this the right way to do it like that?

The Keys/Settings which are used will be (again) hardcoded in the code with default values and possible options, which the user can set. On the registration the default values will be set for the user. 
These information will be in some other classes which i would put into `Test\CoreBundle\Core\Configuration\{category}`

The second "base" question: 
We have some classes which can stay alone. (For example there is a Date/Time class, which do some calculations on the given timestamps) But I don't know where to put it.
If I put them e.g. in "`Services`" it would be sooner or later chaotic.
Putting them in different (based on their functions) in different folders  would be better.

Please let me know any thoughts about the idea and my thoughts. I would love to hear from you.

Update: last thought: Would it be totally wrong to put the classes directly in the namespacefolder "test" ?

Comment: Regarding the configuration service, I'd suggest a factory service which actually creates a concrete configuration object for a given user. E.g. `$factory->createFor($accountId): Configuration`. You could even encapsulate this in the service container.

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks a lot. I will have a look on using a  Factory to Create Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first question is asking if your have your Conf service properly setup and the answer is yes.  At some point you should learn how to define a repository as a service and just inject the repository instead of the complete entity manager.  But that is just a refinement.

The second questions seems to be talking about standalone components.  Make a Test\Component directory and put them under there.  Eventually you may want to put them in their very own repository and use composer to load them.  But that again is a refinement.

If you have not done so already, invest the time to write some automated tests for your migration.  That will give you the power to re-factor as things progress and the design becomes clearer.

Comment: That is the kind of answer I expected. Thanks for your tips. I will experiment a bit with my ideas and your recommendations.